# Unable to take screenshot in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

I am trying to capture a screenshot for each failure occurrence and written following code, but this is not working.

```
public class TestFile {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    @Test   
    public void Testone(){
        driver.get("http://www.google.com/");           
    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
    public void catchExceptions(ITestResult result){
        System.out.println("result"+result);
        String methodName = result.getName();
        System.out.println(methodName);

        if(!result.isSuccess()){         
            try { 
                File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile,new File("C:\\screenshot2.png" ));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is failing at

> File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

---

**stack trace:**

```
[TestNG] Running:
C:\Documents and Settings\537310\Local Settings\Temp\testng-eclipse-1576306112\testng-customsuite.xml

result[TestResult name=Testone status=FAILURE method=TestFile.Testone()[pri:0, instance:com.example.tests.TestFile@1b34126] output={null}]
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod catchExceptions([TestResult name=Testone status=FAILURE method=TestFile.Testone()[pri:0, instance:com.example.tests.TestFile@1b34126] output={null}])
net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException-->Class org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter$CompoundHandler can not access a member of class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver with modifiers "protected"
at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.newInstance(ReflectUtils.java:235)
```

**list of imports:**

```
package com.example.tests;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

Comment: Can you share your imports?

Comment: @ niharika_neo : imports are updated in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stacktrace you shared is not the stacktrace, but I think the testng log. 
The example you provided actually works. I just made the test fail, because in the @AfterMethod a screenshot is taken only if the test fails: if(!result.isSuccess())

Then when I ran the example again, I got:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\screenshot2.png (Access is denied)
Then I changed the location of the picture to be on D: where the permissions are correct, and it worked end to end, I can see the screenshot.

Cheers

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestFile {

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    @Test
    public void Testone() {

        driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
        assert false;

    }

    @AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public void catchExceptions(ITestResult result) {
        System.out.println("result" + result);
        String methodName = result.getName();
        System.out.println(methodName);

        if (!result.isSuccess()) {

            try {

                File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\screenshot2.png"));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi sinisa229 mihajlovski,

Your script is working properly. but there is a slight change in your script. If i won't comment the line "assert false", it is giving error.

Comment: I mention the "assert change" I made in the text before the code. If you remove the assert, there will be no error, but the test will pass with no screenshot taken.

Comment: You are correct, if i comment the assert false line, it is running correctly without taking the screenshot. When i remove the comment, it is taking the screen shot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
 WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
    File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)augmentedDriver).
                        getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
```

In place of

`File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);`

Comment: following error message displayed---FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod catchExceptions([TestResult name=Testone status=FAILURE method=TestFile.Testone()[pri:0, instance:com.example.tests.TestFile@1b273cc] output={null}])
net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException-->Class org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter$CompoundHandler can not access a member of class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver with modifiers "protected"

Comment: Are you using driver.quit() or driver.close() before executing the code of screen capture?I would recommend to change your if condition as  : if (driver != null && driver.getSessionId()!= null && !result.isSuccess())

Comment: Class org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter$CompoundHandler can not access a member of class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver with modifiers "protected" ..This message is displaying

Comment: For problem & fix for that particular exception, see https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5087